# Use parent scope value in filter ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have some Angular code which uses nested ng-repeat like this:

```
 <div ng-repeat="sym in transData.trades | unique:'Symbol'">
    {{sym.Symbol}}
    <div ng-repeat="trans in transData.trades | filter: { Symbol: 'ParentValue' } | orderBy: ['Action']">
        <span>{{trans.Action}}</span>
        <span>{{trans.TxnId}}</span>
        <span>{{trans.Quantity}}</span>
        <span>{{trans.Price}}</span>
        <span>{{trans.MarketValue}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to filter the second ng-repeat by the parent ng-repeat's scope value {{sym.Symbol}} (that's what ParentValue is representing in the second ng-repeat). How can I do that? Using `filter: { Symbol: {{$parent.sym.Symbol}} }` does not work.

Comment: show your controller code and $parent $scope also

Comment: can you provide a plunker to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use **`sym.Symbol`**,

```
<div ng-repeat="sym in transData.trades | unique:'Symbol'">
    {{sym.Symbol}}
    <div ng-repeat="trans in transData.trades | filter: {trans : {Symbol: sym.Symbol}} | orderBy: ['Action']">
        <span>{{trans.Action}}</span>
        <span>{{trans.TxnId}}</span>
        <span>{{trans.Quantity}}</span>
        <span>{{trans.Price}}</span>
        <span>{{trans.MarketValue}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[`DEMO`](https://plnkr.co/edit/HhFBw8Lty0ePFKCsEyPm?p=preview)**

Comment: that didn't work. ng-repeat fails to print anything in this case.

Comment: @dk49 check the demo

Comment: in your plunker, you have not used value from parent scope in second ng-repeat. In filter: {tags: {slug: tag.slug}}, 'tag.slug' doesn't belong to the parent scope. If I replace 'tag.slug' to 'tag.title', the code fails. My code requires picking value from parent scope.

Comment: UPDATE: The method suggested by @Sajeetharan works. I was putting sym.Symnol in single quotes earlier.